# symfony/event-dispatcher not receiving first dispatch

Tags: php, symfony, events

I'm using the [symfony/event-dispatcher](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/event-dispatcher) component and am trying to get a 'hello world' thing to work, I think.

My application (not symfony2) runs `bootstrap.php` then MVC's its way to some file I named `composer.php`.

**bootstrap.php** (the necessary parts)

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Events\MsgEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

if ($user_id) {
    $dispatcher->dispatch('msg_event', new MsgEvent("I'm logged in as: " . $user['username']));
}
```

**composer.php**

```
<?php
use Events\MsgEvent;

$dispatcher->addListener('msg_event', function (MsgEvent $event) {
    echo $event->getMsg();
});

$dispatcher->dispatch('msg_event', new MsgEvent("I got called from composer.php"));
```

On the route for my composer.php page I get to see 'called from composer', but my 'logged in as' message doesn't appear. When I output it's return, I can see it has succesfully created the event.

I have a feeling the problem is that the listener is defined after the first dispatch and somehow this does not get stored in the dispatcher. But I'm not sure.

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Where is comport.php included?

Comment: `index.php` includes `bootstrap.php` which gives a `$controller`, then `layout.php` gets included and in there there's a call to `$controller->page` which will include the final view/`composer.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dispatching the event before registering a listener. Since bootstrap.php is included before composer.php, the first event will fire with no listeners attached to it.

Comment: So that's intended behaviour?

Comment: Definitely. Dispatching is immediate, so when you dispatch the first event it will fire with nothing listening. The event dispatcher is not a message queue, which I think you are confusing it with.